# Have this error Class 'Kohana_Form' on webserver but not locally on WAMP

Tags: kohana, kohana-3.3

```
ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Class 'Kohana_Form' not found
 1 <?php
 2 
 3 defined('SYSPATH') OR die('No direct script access.');
 4 
 5 class Form extends Kohana_Form {
 6
```

I am using some methods such as

```
<?php echo Form::label('contact_name', 'Your Name'); ?>
<?php echo Form::input('contact_name'); ?>
```

This works fine on Windows running WAMP but when I uploaded it to hosting account (LINUX) I get this error, I had some others but they where fixed with a Capital :)

The file names and Capitalization seem fine so im pulling my hair out as to what is going on... using Kohana 3.3.1

Comment: Just to double check, `cd` into your Kohana root directory and run `find -name "Form.php"`. You should have at least `./system/classes/Form.php` and `./system/classes/Kohana/Form.php`. If the case of either the file or directories does not match exactly - this is likely the problem.

Comment: Found both the files.. thanks for the help but I gave up not much up to date documentation on this framework, im looking at CodeIgnitor now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check, if there is a class named Kohana_Form (do not ignore case!) or just uncomment this line: `spl_autoload_register(array('Kohana', 'auto_load_lowercase'));` in `bootstrap.php`